# Error deploying SQL database: User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express, publish, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET app with an MS SQL 2008 database. Everything works dandy on my local machine and I want to perform a web deployment using Visual studio on the test server. But when I try to publish the app on my Win 2003 server, I get the following error:

Web deployment task failed.((21/08/2012 16:33:04) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(21/08/2012 16:33:04) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The database 'c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\LDashboard\App_Data\SQADB.mdf' could not be created.
User does not have permission to perform this action.

Now the user specified in my publish profile has full control on that machine and also on the SQL server (by that, I mean it appears in the Logins section in SQL Management Studio and has all the server roles checked).

The source DB connection string is :

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SQADB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True

And the target DB connection string I've configured is:

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\LDashboard\App_Data\SQADB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True

What am I missing?